# Strange notification progress bar issue

Tags: java, android, push-notification, progress-bar

Developing an app, where when a user download content from my app, then a push notification with progress bar is shown. In kitkat its working great, while downloading its showing the progress bar, and progress bar finish when download is complete, while testing the same in Android 7.0 and 8.0, here after the content downloaded then also progress bar never completes. Below is my cropped code of progress bar -

```
// background task to download file
    private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Void> {
        NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

                // Configure the notification channel.
                notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }

            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(VideoPlayActivity.this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("File Download")
                    .setContentText("Download in progress")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.doupnowlogo);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading file...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String...params){
            URL url;
            int count;
            try {
                url = new URL(params[0].replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
                String pathl="";
                try {
                    File f=new File(storeDir);
                    if(f.exists()){
                        HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                        InputStream is=con.getInputStream();
                        String pathr=url.getPath();
                        String filename=pathr.substring(pathr.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                        pathl=storeDir+"/"+filename;
                        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(pathl);
                        int lenghtOfFile = con.getContentLength();
                        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                        long total = 0;
                        while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
                            total += count;
                            // publishing the progress
                            publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                            // writing data to output file
                            fos.write(data, 0, count);
                        }

                        is.close();
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.e("Error","Not found: "+storeDir);

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);
            // Displays the progress bar on notification
            mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete");
            // Removes the progress bar
            //mBuilder.setProgress(0,0,false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

if any more code is required then please let me know, I will update it here.